# magento 2 table with no auto increment column catalog_product_relation

Tags: magento2, auto-increment

Table `catalog_product_relation` dosn't comes with the auto increment column. i want to create a custom id col with auto increment with the following query but not working. please help

ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_relation` ADD `custom_id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

i am getting error called `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query generated in adminer while altering table

[image]

**Query:**

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_relation`
ADD `custom_id` int unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Auto Increment' 
AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
```